# bam-readcount: command not found

Tags: github, bam

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvbBp.png)
I tried installing readcount for BAM files from (https://github.com/genome/bam-readcount) by retracting the latest release version from Docker with

```
docker pull mgibio/bam-readcount
git clone https://github.com/genome/bam-readcount 
cd bam-readcount
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
# Executable is
bin/bam-readcount
```

but when trying the command, it says *the command is not found* as can be seen in the picture. Can someone help me how to run bam-readcount properly? Thank you in advance!